# A further popup appears despite URLAllowlist policy ("Open fooHandler.bat?"). How do I get rid of it?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, url, popup, registry

The title is a bit wonky, feel free to edit to something clearer if need be.

I've been tasked to write a script, which is called from a batch file (let's nickname it "fooHandler.bat"), which itself is called by a Base-64 Encoded message put into the Google Chrome search bar (the script eventually takes care of decoding the message into actual data). To make this all work, some policies have been added to the Registry Editor :

[image: UrlAllowList Policy]

[image: Protocol Policy Folder]

[image: Command Policy]

The URLAllowlist policy prevents a "Open URL:foo Protocol?" popup from appearing, while the foobar\shell\open\command policy actually executes fooHandler.bat when the URL is put on Chrome (example "foobar:VGhpcyBpcyBkdW1teSBkYXRh").

All of this works on my local machine, but on another machine (where the whole thing got deployed for testing), an additional, unexpected popup appears :

[image: Unexpected Popup]

Would you happen to know what's causing it to appear, and what I can do to get rid of it ?